# Apache POI docx - after modified the target docx file, file corrupt

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I had write a code by using Apache POI 3.6.
The code is use to insert paragraph ,table and image to one docx file, but as the paragraph, table and image is from different docx file, so I need to read content from different docx file then insert to the target file.
But I found the file is only readable at the first content insert, so is there any thing need to be changed?
My method defined like following:

```
public class DocDomGroupUtilImpl implements DocDomGroupUtil {

private FileInputStream fips;
private XWPFDocument document;
private FileOutputStream fops;

@Override
public void generateDomGroupFile(File templateFile, List<Item> items) {

    // initial parameters
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (Item item : items) {
        parameters.put(item.getParaName(), item.getParaValue());
    }

    // get domGroup type
    String templateFileName = templateFile.getName();
    String type = templateFileName.substring(0, templateFileName.indexOf("."));

    try {
        fips = new FileInputStream(templateFile);
        document = new XWPFDocument(fips);

        // create tempt file for document domGroup, named like
        // docDomGroup_<type>_<domName>.docx
        String domGroupFilePath = CONSTAINTS.temptDomGroupPath + "docDomGroup_" + type + "_"
                + parameters.get("$DomGroupName_Value") + ".docx";

        File domGroupFile = new File(domGroupFilePath);

        if (domGroupFile.exists()) {
            domGroupFile.delete();
        }

        domGroupFile.createNewFile();
        fops = new FileOutputStream(domGroupFile, true);

        // modified the groupName
        // replace content
        String regularExpression = "\\$(.*)_Value";

        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
            List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();

            if (runs != null) {
                for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
                    String text = run.getText(0);
                    if (text != null && Pattern.matches(regularExpression, text)) {
                        text = parameters.get(text);
                        run.setText(text, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        document.write(fops);
        close();

        // copy all the information from dom related files
        File dir = new File(CONSTAINTS.temptDomPath);
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                fops = new FileOutputStream(domGroupFile, true);
                fips = new FileInputStream(file);
                document = new XWPFDocument(fips);
                document.write(fops);
            }
            close();
        }

        // clean up tempt dom folder removeAllDomFile();
        removeAllDomFile();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}

/**
 * remove all the generated tempt dom files
 */
private void removeAllDomFile() {
    // loop directory and delete tempt file
    File dir = new File(CONSTAINTS.temptDomPath);
    for (File file : dir.listFiles())
        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            file.delete();
        }
}

private void close() {
    try {
        fips.close();
        fops.flush();
        fops.close();
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A `*.docx` file is a `ZIP` archive containing a directory structure containing `XML`files and other files too (pictures for example). This is **not** a file format where the content can simply be appended. Each `XWPFDocument.write(OutputStream)` writes the whole structure into the `OutputStream`. So what you are doing here is concatenating multiple `ZIP` archives one after the other in one file. This can not work. Your requirement is complex. Do a research using key words "merge multiple word documents apache poi".

Comment: Thank you Axel Richter! I will try!